# I want to create a window manager dialog when incoming call is detected but click event is not working

Tags: android, window

I want to create a window manager dialog when incoming call is detected but click event is not working

I want click event in the dialog and outside the dialog as I would want to receive calls

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

use code.

LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    2003,
                    262184,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

work properly..